# Is there a way to combine and optimize selectors in SASS stylesheets?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Is there any good practices or tools for merging similar selectors and optimizing SCSS source?

For example having this:

```css
#left .menu 
{
     //Content a 
}

#left .menu span
{
     //Content b 
}

#left .menu 
{
     //Content c 
}
```

Turn into this:

```
#left .menu 
{
     //Content a
     //Content c 

     span
     {
          //Content b 
     }

}
```

It's tedious to do this by hand, especially for larger stylesheets where the structure might not be so apparent. One could put more effort into writing leaner and cleaner SCSS, but it should be some tidy SCSS tool out there, or is there a best practice I'm missing?

Comment: Nesting selectors is not a requirement for Sass.  Rearranging styles is something that should be done by hand because it alters the cascade order.

Comment: If you are working on a big project you should create separate SCSS files for each section in your work for comfortable reasons, one of them is avoid duplicates selectors. see `@import` in http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My problem lies in writing clean and more maintanable SCSS. I want a way to combine selector nodes into an optimized hierarchy. When I need to add styles to a stylesheet I would love to write several cascading styles in correct order, and have a tidy SCSS tool merge my different trees, into one optimized one. Seems like there are no tools for this currently. It is cumbersome to manually traverse the hierarchy to find the correct selector.

Answer (score 5):

I would agree with the comment by @cimmanon on your question, but if you must, try [this css2sass converter](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/).

The input I gave it:

```
#left .menu 
{
     //Content a 
}

#left .menu span
{ 
     //Content b 
}

#left .menu 
{
     //Content c 
}
```

The output:

```
#left .menu {
  //Content a
  span {
    //Content b

  }
  //Content c
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`sass-convert`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/) should meet your needs:

$ sass-convert --to scss your-example.css

```
#left .menu {
  //Content a
  span {
    //Content b

 }
 //Content c
}
```